# Amazon Kindle (Paperwhite) not recognized

Tags: kindle

I have a newly bought Amazon Paperwhite, but when I connect it to my PC, Ubuntu does not recognize it.

What can I do?

Comment: Read [Managing Kindle Fire with on 12.04 via Micro-USB](http://askubuntu.com/questions/177555/managing-kindle-fire-with-on-12-04-via-micro-usb) . I think your problem is the same.

Comment: What firmware version for **Kindle Paperwhite**? eg. 5.3.1 (My own device does connect to **12.04**.)

Comment: @Antigona: The **Paperwhite** does not appear to be using **MTP**, under 5.3.1 or 5.3.3 firmware. Also supports Calibre.

Answer (score 13):

I suggest trying different cables, it finally solved my problem in the end after having lost some time (Paperwhite connecting to Ubuntu Xenial).

Store-bought cables laying around appeared to only be capable of charging the device. A Huawei P9 lite original cable was the one that finally made the connection.

Comment: was the problem in my case. I used a chromecast cable (which usually works for charging)
Changing to the usual data cable worked.

Comment: Same here... the cable was also the problem for me

Answer (score 7):

I've stumbled upon the same problem. After installing **mtpfs** all worked fine.

```
sudo apt-get install mtpfs
```

Don't forget to remove and insert the usb cable again.

FYI: Mine is a Kindle Touch.

Comment: From what I can tell, the Paperwhite does not use MTP. It uses USB Mass Storage. Simply plugging the device in should work. I see no options for what protocol to use, either, on my Paperwhite.

Comment: This answer is a solution if you have a "normal" Kindle. I have Kindle 5 and it worked for me.

Comment: I have a "normal" kindle too and that didn't work, it was already installed.

Comment: mtpfs and USB mass storage both do not work on Xenial, still, with a Paperwhite. Would appreciate any solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to turn off the Airplane Mode on your kindle. For me, this solved it, but it took me a while to realize that it was on.

There can many reasons why one could have a problem with the USB connection, and this is one of them. Apparently, the airplane mode also disables USB, and not only network connection.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to install calibre `sudo apt-get install calibre`, and manage your Kindle Paperwhite. I don't have a new-ish kindle to test with, but that method has worked with the older kindles, and I don't think they changed it much.

Comment: Doesn't work in Xenial. I guess Calibre just relies on MTP or USB mass storage to work, which it doesn't with my Paperwhite.