# Ubuntu Phone BQ Aquaris E4.5 USB Problem

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, phone

I do not appear to have any USB Functionality on my BQ Aquarius Ubuntu Edition Phone.  Plugged into Dell running Ubuntu 12.04 and neither the phone nor the Laptop see each other.  USB power okay and cable okay as it was tested with a Moto Defy.  Is there actually any USB functionality with the Ubuntu Aquarius?  I was expecting at least to see my 32GB SD card - which is basically all I want.

Comment: I there i have mine BQ Aquaris E4.5 and it working fine i can see the phone memory and the micro SD Card but i'm using the 14.04 LTS on desktop, try using a live image of Ubuntu 14.04 or higher and see if it work ??

Comment: USB access of newer phones including the aquaris is done via MTP. MTP is supported out of the box since Ubuntu 13.04. If upgrading is an option you should do that. Otherwise you would have to install a MTP tool and MTP drivers of somekind. If you need more info about that because upgrading is not possible feel free to ask.

Comment: I fixed it with a response someone gave to add MTP from repository but I cannot find that response now.  It was an easy fix that worked.  The Ubuntu Aquaris phone cannot be seen on 12.04 without this - possible other distros.  This was a perfect fix - just do not understand where the response disappeared to so I could share its success.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu touch does not allow USB interaction as long as the phone screen is locked. Even if it is only locked by slide, this can block the interaction. I also made sure my screen doesn't lock after idleness, so this locking doesn't happen halfway through a transfer.

Also, ~/.android/adb_usb.ini on your computer is a list of valid vendorIDs that are allowed to connect. I found that list empty (or non existent, don't remember, doesn't matter). Just add a new line with the vendorID for your phone:
If you have MX4, add 0x2a45, if Aquaris E4.5, the ID is 0x2a47. Otherwise look it up by using lsusb. You can of course also add both to be sure ;)

~/.android/adb_usb.ini :

```
0x2a45
0x2a47
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a tour [here](https://launchpad.net/~fossfreedom/+archive/ubuntu/libmtp) to upgrade your MTP library.
Hope it could help.

Comment: Although your link is helpful, the answer itself is not. What do we do to upgrade our MTP library? Please elaborate/expand.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my 2 cents because I was also struggling with this and my solution was really weird.

Fresh install of ubuntu 14.04.2 64-bit with all updates installed.

Connected phone with usb **2.0** port: **no access** (I tried 2 different usb 2.0 ports)

Connected phone with usb **2.0** port and used **gMTP** (ubuntu software center): **access**

Connected phone with usb **3.0** port: **access** (no need for gMTP)

Comment: Thanks! Just received my Moto E 2nd gen and was unable to get access to the SD card until I tried your third option, connect it to my PC's USB 3.0 port. Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-Bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my BQ Ubuntuphone and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The phone is not recognized at all when connected via USB. Are there any settings required on either side?

Comment: Have you tried unlocking as Maarten Klop suggested? If your phone is on the lock screen it won't mount the device or the SD card.

Comment: This is not an answer. If you want to say that you have the same issue, then use the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to unlock the phone if it is PIN protected. Once unlocked you should be able to see phone content

Answer (score 0):

I managed to access the files on my phone following the instructions here: [Managing Kindle Fire with on 12.04 via Micro-USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177555/managing-kindle-fire-with-on-12-04-via-micro-usb).

It is a threat about connecting a Kindle, but it worked beautifylly for me. Maybe it could be of use for you.