# usb mount problem to aquarisE4.5

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, mtp

Regardless of restarts, I cannot connect with USB to my AquarisE4.5 through my file browser anymore.

First it says:

*No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Mount' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/mount/1.*

Then on next attempt:

*Unable to open MTP device '[usb:002,003]'.*

Screen on phone is unlocked and active while I'm trying to connect.

I also tried with an alternative libmtp ppa, according to this post [Ubuntu Phone BQ Aquaris E4.5 USB Problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602488/ubuntu-phone-bq-aquaris-e4-5-usb-problem) but it seems already to be latest versions as no updates are pending in my update manager.

Phone is running Ubuntu Utopic Unicorn 14.10 (r21), PC is running Linux Mint Xfce 17.1 Rebecca (Ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was Banshee's MTP support, throwing/blocking the phone.

I've made a new thread here for this separate issue:

[Banshee throws the mtp connection to my phone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623033/banshee-throws-the-mtp-connection-to-my-phone)