# Banshee throws the mtp connection to my phone

Tags: banshee, mtp, aquaris

When my AquarisE4.5 Ubuntu phone is connected by USB and I fire up Banshee (with MTP support), it throws the phone mount, and I can't remount until Banshee is closed. Syslog said:

> May 13 05:30:10 CANTANDO kernel: [  500.700012] usb 2-1: reset
>   high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
>
> May 13 05:30:10
>   CANTANDO kernel: [  500.715964] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: xHCI
>   xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800a03aa700
>
> May 13 05:30:10 CANTANDO kernel: [  500.718658] usb 2-1: usbfs: process
>   4181 (banshee) did not claim interface 0 before use [...]

When I removed the MTP support on Banshee, the problem disappeared.

Is there a way for these two things to coexist?

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround if you don't want Banshee to mount your phone ever.
Open up preferences in Banshee without your phone plugged in and disable the "MTP Media Player Support" under 'extensions/Device Support'. 
Then restart banshee and plugin your phone.

Now Banshee does not mount your phone.
Works for me.